# Adaptation for a mobile device, Google does not see that it is adaptive

Tags: html, css, layout, joomla, adaptive-layout

(Google translate)

https://elenanovias.com/en/

There is a site,  I adapted it under the mobile., But search.google says that the site is not adaptive

`viewport`

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ,  maximum-scale=1.0,  user-scalable=yes  ">`

I made a site on joomla 2.5. I read something, maybe that's the problem?
Note: Joomla! 2.5 is end of life since December 2014. Joomla! 3.x is mobile friendly out of the box.

In the styles I use:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {`

not

`@media (max-width: 768px)`

Need more information, write.

[image: my site]

[image: google]

[image: another picture]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: The large images you have on the site may be influencing Google's decision. Having so many images like that will cause your site to load very slowly over a mobile data connection. Try optimising the images.

Comment: @Billy Moa i added another picture with google

Comment: @Billy Moa I made a site on joomla 2.5. I read something, maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the user-scalable=yes and you should be good.

Comment: I made a site on joomla 2.5. I read something, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I did the mobile friendly test myself and google points out the 2 problems that cause the site to be rated as not mobile-friendly. Solving them wil probably help ;)

Comment: I made a site on joomla 2.5. I read something, maybe that's the problem?
Note: Joomla! 2.5 is end of life since December 2014. Joomla! 3.x is mobile friendly out of the box. @CheapGame

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

The problem was in `robors.txt`. Google.console could not get all the styles, I registered the absolute path: `/ folder / folder / folder / style.css`, and voila.

I received this project from another developer, and there was a lot of trash.

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /*.css  //skipped such a path (although it should work)
Allow: /templates/elenanovias/css/style.css  //with this path it all worked
```